# How to check if a specific word has a number next to it?

Tags: java

I Need to verify if the "Page" word in string has a integer next it.

Need to check if its a page number or just a content of the page.

The data is coming from an xml file in this format.

This is a sample data that has a page number

```
String strLineText ="<Line><![CDATA[AB1234 Date 02/31/18                       Company  1234 Very Big Company              USD                               Page    1]]></Line>";`
```

The spaces between page and number is not definite.

This is a sample data has a page word in it

```
String strLineText ="<Line><![CDATA[1234AB1234    -  1234-       Page Cash Savings]]></Line>";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regular expression as follows:

`"Page\\s+\\d+"`

However, be warned, regex and markup in general doesn't work well together, so use this only to find instances, not to parse the document contextually.

**Full example**

```
String hasPageNumber = "<Line><![CDATA[AB1234 Date 02/31/18                       Company  1234 Very Big Company              USD                               Page    1]]></Line>";
String noPageNumber = "<Line><![CDATA[1234AB1234    -  1234-       Page Cash Savings]]></Line>";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Page\\s+\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(hasPageNumber);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("Found: %s%n", m.group());
}
else {
    System.out.println("Not found");
}
m = p.matcher(noPageNumber);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("Found: %s%n", m.group());
}
else {
    System.out.println("Not found");
}
```

**Output**

```
Found: Page    1
Not found
```

Comment: True words of wisdom.

Comment: @Neil thanks. Lesson learned the hard way on my side, back in the day :D

Comment: I think we all have at one point.  As they say, if you have a problem and you want to fix it using regular expressions..

Comment: @Neil finishing your sentence: "you now have **two** problems" :)

Comment: @Mena using "Page\\s*\\d+" seems better to me cuz if there is a chance that it will be no space between the Page and the number

Comment: @Billydan well the OP hasn't specified this as an edge-case, so I would presume there will always be at least one whitespace character between `"Page"` and the digit(s), i.e. no `"Page1"` instance.

Comment: @Mena Thanks a lot for the quick answer. It's working properly now.

Answer (score 1):

```
String hasPageNumber = "<Line><![CDATA[AB1234 Date 02/31/18                       Company  1234 Very Big Company              USD                               Page          1]]></Line>";
String noPageNumber = "<Line><![CDATA[1234AB1234    -  1234-       Page Cash Savings]]></Line>"
if(hasPageNumber.matches("(.*)Page *\\d+(.*)")){
    System.out.println("yes");
}
```

Comment: Above code is an another alternative which can be used and good in performance and easiest way to match the string, i had tested   regular expression  for few cases it works .

Comment: Thanks Rajesh for the answer.